# WPF Trigger TextBox BorderBrush not working

Tags: wpf, triggers, textbox

when I try to set a different `BorderBrush` for the `TextBox` when it is focused using the following (simplified) style it does not work.

```
<Style x:Key="{x:Type TextBox}" TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">        
    <Style.Triggers>            
        <Trigger Property="IsFocused" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Red" />
        </Trigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

However, if instead of setting a different `BorderBrush` I try to e.g. set the `Background` (i.e. `<Setter Property="Background" Value="Red" />`) it does work.

I tried the solutions saying I should try setting the `BorderThickness` to something like `0.99` or `1.01` as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6120495/7571171) and [here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/327e86b5-8da3-47ad-88fc-547f8da5f261/how-change-border-color-on-a-textbox?forum=wpf) but they do not work for me.

Any help is gladly appreciated.

Comment: read this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36605387/wpf-textbox-border-style-trigger-isfocused-only-works-if-has-focus-but-not-keybo

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What is going on is that the `TextBoxBase` has some triggers for `IsFocused`, so your trigger is overriden by the default one.

You should modify the `TextBoxBase` template and put your trigger there to achieve what you want :

```
<TextBox.Style>
    <Style
        TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
        <Setter
            Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate
                    TargetType="{x:Type TextBoxBase}">
                    <Border
                        x:Name="border"
                        BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                        BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"
                        Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                        SnapsToDevicePixels="True">
                        <ScrollViewer
                            x:Name="PART_ContentHost"
                            Focusable="False"
                            HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden"
                            VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden" />
                    </Border>
                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        <Trigger
                            Property="IsFocused"
                            Value="True">
                            <Setter
                                Property="BorderBrush"
                                Value="Red" />
                        </Trigger>
                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>

    </Style>
</TextBox.Style>
```